# Proving weaker exists based on forall

Tags: coq

```
Lemma one_bigger' : forall n h, 
   n = S (double h) -> (exists k, S n = double k).
Proof.
  intros n h H.  rewrite H. exists (S h). reflexivity.
Qed.

Lemma one_bigger : forall n, 
   (exists k, n = S (double k)) -> (exists k, S n = double k).
Admitted.
```

It seems to me that the second lemma should be trivially provable given the first, but I can't seem to wrap my head around how to use the first lemma to prove the second one.

Answer (score 1):

`case H` seems to be the magic I couldn't find:

```
Lemma one_bigger : forall n, 
   (exists k, n = S (double k)) -> (exists k, S n = double k).
Proof.
  intros n H. case H. apply one_bigger'.
Qed.
```

Comment: or `destruct H.`  or `intros n [k H].`

Comment: Thanks! I definitely should have thought of the `intros` variant, I was forgetting about that completely.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, your example is an instance of an equivalence (Lemma `L`)

```
Section S1.
  Variable (A :Type).
  Variables (P : A -> Prop) (Q:  Prop).
  
  Lemma L : (forall x , P x  -> Q ) <-> ((exists x, P x) -> Q). 
   Proof.
    split.
    - intros H [x Hx]; now apply (H x).
    - intros H x Hx; apply H. now exists x.
  Qed.
End S1.

Lemma one_bigger'' : forall n, 
    (exists k, n = S (double k)) -> (exists k, S n = double k).
Proof. 
  intros n .
  rewrite <- L . 
  apply one_bigger'. 
Qed.
```

Comment: Thanks! This works perfectly, though I don't know what `firstorder` is yet so I may confine myself to the more basic approaches until I've learned more...

Comment: I edited my post, using more basic tactics in `L`'s proof.

Answer (score 0):

If you use SSReflect, you can write your proof as follows.

```
From mathcomp Require Import all_ssreflect.

Set Implicit Arguments.
Unset Strict Implicit.
Unset Printing Implicit Defensive.

Lemma one_bigger' : forall n h, 
   n = S (double h) -> (exists k, S n = double k).
Proof.
  intros n h H.  rewrite H. exists (S h). reflexivity.
Qed.

Lemma one_bigger : forall n, 
   (exists k, n = S (double k)) -> (exists k, S n = double k).
Proof. by move=> n [k /one_bigger']. Qed.
```

The `move` construct does the same as `intros`, except that your `H` is here directly destructured into a witness, `k`, and a proof of the equality in the existential. This last proof is directly passed to `one_bigger'` via the `/` notation, thus yielding the expected result.

Another, more explicit proof would be

```
Proof. move=> n [k eqn]. exists k.+1. by rewrite eqn doubleS. Qed.
```

Comment: I guess I am not using `SSReflect` because the response I get from coq is
`Syntax error: illegal begin of vernac` on the `by` of the input. I will try again when I eventually learn what SSReflect is :)

Comment: I updated my answer with the commands to put at the start of a file to be able to use SSReflect.

Comment: Thanks for updating your answer. Looks like I don't have `mathcomp` installed and would need to also follow the instructions here: https://math-comp.github.io/installation.html ... this I have still not attempted.